# How do I resolve the error "Cannot access a disposed context instance" from a SignalR action in my ASP.NET Core 5 web application?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asynchronous, kendo-ui, signalr

I am using a KendoUI SignalR Bound grid in my web application.  The grid is editable and allows the user to delete records by click on a small trash can icon.  In this particular instance the item being deleted has a lot of related data in different tables.

I am using a generic repository pattern with dependency injection inside of my hub controller to handle the read/destroy/update events of the grid.

Here is my hub controller at the moment:

```
public async void Destroy(ViewNewswires model)
    {
        IEnumerable<NewswireCharterer> nwc = _newswireCharterer.GetAll().Where(x => x.Newswire_Id == model.Id).ToList();
        IEnumerable<NewswireOwner> nwo = _newswireOwner.GetAll().Where(x => x.Newswire_Id == model.Id).ToList();
        IEnumerable<NewswireProject> nwp = _newswireProject.GetAll().Where(x => x.Newswire_Id == model.Id).ToList();
        IEnumerable<NewswireRegion> nwr = _newswireRegion.GetAll().Where(x => x.Newswire_Id == model.Id).ToList();
        IEnumerable<NewswireScope> nws = _newswireScope.GetAll().Where(x => x.Newswire_Id == model.Id).ToList();
        IEnumerable<NewswireVessel> nwv = _newswireVessel.GetAll().Where(x => x.Newswire_Id == model.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var charterer in nwc) {
            await _newswireCharterer.DeleteAsync(charterer);
        };
        
        foreach (var owner in nwo)
        {
            await _newswireOwner.DeleteAsync(owner);
        };
        
        foreach (var project in nwp)
        {
            await _newswireProject.DeleteAsync(project);
        };
        
        foreach (var region in nwr)
        {
            await _newswireRegion.DeleteAsync(region);
        };
        
        foreach (var scope in nws)
        {
            await _newswireScope.DeleteAsync(scope);
        };
        
        foreach (var vessel in nwv)
        {
            await _newswireVessel.DeleteAsync(vessel);
        };
        Newswire nw = _newswires.GetAll().Where(x => x.Id == model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        await _newswires.DeleteAsync(nw);

        await Clients.OthersInGroup(GetGroupName()).SendAsync("destroy", model);
    }
```

You'll see from the above action, there are a few context instances used and those are declared as lists, the reason for that is to prevent the data-reader open error that can occur when using dependency injection in this way.  Additionally, the action is asynchronous for the sole purpose of ensuring that each operation in completed before moving on to the next one, failure to make this asynchronous has caused conflicting thread errors.

When I try to delete an item from the grid using the above action configuration I get the error:

> Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this
> error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from
> dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context
> instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are
> calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using
> statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the
> dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances.

This had me thinking that perhaps the `.ToList()` was causing this issue so I removed it, when I did this, naturally I get the error that there is an open data reader which is undisposed.  So my question is, how can I fix this and make this delete action work correctly?

Here is my repository for reference:

***IRepository.cs***

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyCompany.Repo
{
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        Task<TEntity> CreateAsync(TEntity entity);
        Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity);
        Task<TEntity> DeleteAsync(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

***Repository.cs***

```
namespace MyCompany.Repo
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

        protected readonly HaglandContext _context;
        #endregion

        public Repository(HaglandContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                return _context.Set<TEntity>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Couldn't retrieve entities: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }        
        public async Task<TEntity> CreateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(CreateAsync)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                await _context.AddAsync(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be saved: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        public async Task<TEntity> DeleteAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(DeleteAsync)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                _context.Remove(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be saved: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        public async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(CreateAsync)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                _context.Update(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be updated: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Grid.js***

```
function load_newswire_grid(e) {    
    let go = $('#newswire_grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {            
            autoSync: true,
            pageSize: 100,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id"                   
                }
            },
            type: "signalr",
            sort: [
                {
                    field: "Id", 
                    dir: "desc"
                },
            ],
            transport: {                
                signalr: {
                    promise: market_hub_start,
                    hub: market_hub,
                    server: {
                        read: "read",
                        update: "update",
                        create: "create",
                        destroy: "destroy"
                    },//server
                    client: {
                        read: "read",
                        update: "update",
                        create: "create",
                        destroy: "destroy"
                    }//client
                }//signalr
            }//transport
        },//dataSource
        filterable: true,
        autoBind: true,             
        reorderable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        editable: "inline",

        columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                field: "Newswire_Title",
                title: "Source",
                template: '<a href="\\#pablo" data-newswire-id="#=Id#" onclick="open_newswire_window(this)">#=Newswire_Title#</a>'
            },
            {
                field: "Newswire_Text",
                title: "Text",
                template: "<div data-bs-toggle='popover' data-bs-trigger='hover' data-bs-html='true' data-bs-content='#=kendo.toString(Newswire_Text)#'><span>#=Newswire_Text#</span></div>"
            },
            {
                field: "Vessel_Names",
                title: "Vessels",
                template: "#if(Vessel_Names !=null) {# #=vessel_tag_template(data)# #} {# #} #"
            },
            {
                field: "Charterer_Names",
                title: "Charterers",
                width: 200,
                template: "#if(Charterer_Names !=null) {# #=charterer_tag_template(data)# #} else {# #} #"
            },
            {
                field: "Owner_Names",
                title: "Owners",
                width: 200,
                template: "#if(Owner_Names !=null) {# #=owner_tag_template(data)# #} else {# #} #"
            },
            {
                field: "Scope_Name",
                title: "Scopes",
                width: 200,
                template: "#if(Scope_Name !=null) {# #=scope_tag_template(data)# #} else {##} #"
            },
            {
                field: "Region_Names",
                title: "Regions",
                width: 200,
                template: "#if(Region_Names !=null) {# #=region_tag_template(data)# #} else {# #} #"
            },
            {
                field: "Project",
                title: "Project",
                width: 200,
                template: "#if(Region_Names !=null) {# #=project_tag_template(data)# #} else {# #} #"
            },
            {
                field: "Created_Date",
                title: "Created",
                width: 100,

                template: "#if(Created_Date !=null) {# <div data-toggle='popover' data-content='#=Created_User#' data-trigger='hover'>#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Created_Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd/MM/yyyy')#</div> #} #"
            },
            {
                title: "&nbsp;",
                width: 40,
                template: '<div class="text-end dark-grid-button-group"><button class="k-button k-grid-delete"><span class="k-icon k-i-trash"></span></button></div>'
            }
        ]//columns
    })//kendoGrid;
}//function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your "HaglandContext" registered as transient or scoped service? ( should probably be scoped )

Is your "Repository{TEntity}" registered as transient or scoped service? ( should probably be transient )

Some injection missmatch exists between your repo and context probably

Comment: The repository is added as a transient as follows: `services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));` and the context is added as a `DbContext` as follows: ` services.AddDbContext<HaglandContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Hagland.Repo")));`